# Normed linear space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Hello I was given a take home true or false questionnaire to study for a final without the answer key and was hoping you could let me out. The question is:

> If $X$ is a normed linear space, with norm $\|\cdot\|$, then the assignment $(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ defines an inner product on $X$.

I marked this as True.

Comment: I suggest you go and look at (i.e. study) the definitions of norm and inner product? I think you will find the answer there. If, after  studying these definitions, you have a specific question about the definitions, then post it and someone might help.

Answer (score 1):

Unless $X=\{0\}$, it's not true: since $(x,x)=0$ for all $x$, we cannot have definiteness.

Also, the RHS is not (sesqui)-linear.